# modrewrite rule not allowing CSS file to load

Tags: css, mod-rewrite

I'm a total noob when it comes to modrewrite and I wrote the following rewrite rule in  my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ teams.php?team=$1&year=$2 [L]
```

That rule effectively makes a link like

```
teams.php?team=Cincinnati Reds&year=2012
```

Become
    /Cininnati Reds/2012

But the css file wont load. I tried changing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/conceptually.css" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/conceptually.css" />
```

With no luck.

Any ideas about how to make any quick rewrite rules that I would write so that I don't have to to into each file and change the directory to each CSS file.

---

#### EDIT:

Actually, I would ideally like the URL to be `teams/Cincinnati Reds/2012` and not just `/Cincinnati Reds/2012`. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Shouldn't this belong in ServerFault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following two rewrite-conditions to not use rewriting for all real files and directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# your RewriteRule here…
```

Btw. with mod_rewrite, you rewrite a URL from `/Cininnati Reds/2012` to `teams.php?team=Cincinnati Reds&year=2012`. mod_rewrite does not turn your links into that format. That is left to the displaying application.

Comment: And actually, I would ideally want the URL to be teams/Cincinnati Reds/2012 and not just /Cincinnati Reds/2012. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For your second request, this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^teams/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ teams.php?team=$1&year=$2 [L]
```